# Post-apocalyptic book with snake-like aliens teaching children to fight

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I read a book years ago, and I can't remember too much about it. The setting was in a post apocalyptic future and something of the sort, but from what I do remember, there were tall snake-like aliens (monsters, mutants, something of the sort) that raised small children in an egg-like dome. When they reached a certain age they were taken out into a yard with a fence. They continued to teach the children things, and the main character met "Zane" they were best friends. The aliens taught the children about violence by making them watch a Cock-fight and then strapping blades on their hands and feet, the main character has to fight Zane to the death and kills him. Then the main character manages to escape and meets up with a group of people. Meets a woman, fights in some battles. The group of people he meets up with are like super radical american patriots. Then the main character sees the aliens again and uses their weapon a "rod that is ran by emotions" and kills most of, if not all of, them.

Comment: I don't know what the book is called, but I must say, it sounds like an interesting book :)

Comment: Any chance you could tell us how long "years ago" was, was it 2 years, 5 years, 50 years?

Comment: i read it within the last 10 years

Comment: @MrPie Upon going through my garage I came across the book. The book is called "The Bite of Monsters" by Dennis O'Neil and in rereading it its very dark, and was copyrighted in 1971, there's a lot of trigger warnings I could give. However, if you have the stomach for it its incredible.

Comment: @Edlothiad Upon going through my garage I came across the book. The book is called "The Bite of Monsters" by Dennis O'Neil and in rereading it its very dark, and was copyrighted in 1971, there's a lot of trigger warnings I could give. However, if you have the stomach for it its incredible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upon going through my garage I came across the book. The book is called "The Bite of Monsters" by Dennis O'Neil and in rereading it its very dark, and was copyrighted in 1971, there's a lot of trigger warnings I could give. However, if you have the stomach for it its incredible.

Comment: Can you give a little more of a summary of the book, to provide some hooks for others searching for it in the future?